# How to add additional input fields to the form generated by useraccounts:bootstrap in MeteorJS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I am using **useraccounts:bootstrap** package to develop a custom user registration form.

```
<template name="login">
    {{> atForm}}
</template>
```

The above template generates a **login form** with *Email, Password* fields and a **registration form** with *Email, Password, Password (Again)* fields.

How to add fields *( like First Name, Last Name, Address )* other than *Email, Password, Password (Again)* to the generated registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a configuration file like `accountConfig.js`, add the required fields there and import this file to `main.js` of client.

For example your `accountConfig.js` will be like this:

```
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
{
    _id: 'firstName',
    type: 'text',
    displayName: 'First Name',
    placeholder: 'Your First Name',
},
{
    _id: 'lastName',
    type: 'text',
    displayName: 'Last Name',
    placeholder: 'Your Last Name',
},
{
    _id: 'address',
    type: 'text',
    displayName: "Address",
    placeholder: "Your postal address",
    required: true,
},
```

]);

Comment: Thank you. That worked fine. And where can I find documentations regarding this package?

Comment: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#configuration-api